# How can I programmatically uninstall a font in Windows?

Tags: c#, fonts

I have tried searching for an answer to this but I cannot find anything on SO which is much to my surprise, I thought for sure this must have been asked in the past...

I have a requirement to remove/uninstall a font from the windows directory using a C# .Net (version 4) application. The font in question is usually found somewhere like: `C:/Windows/Fonts`

My initial thoughts was that I can just delete the file (using `File.Delete(...)`), but I am unsure if this is enough? My worry comes from the installation of fonts... if you copy a file to the font folder then you get a dialog saying the font is installing.

If deleting the file is enough then I am happy to do so, or is their a more recommended way that this should be done?

If it makes any difference then the OS is Windows XP and the fonts are custom fonts but I am not sure what the original install method was

---

As clearly posting on StackOverflow with a tag of C# isn't apparently enough... **I want to do this from a C# .Net (version 4) application**.

Comment: You might want to elaborate on how this is programming-related, otherwise it's going to gather misguided close votes.

Comment: Erm... this is StackOverflow and I have tagged this as C#... do I really need to explain I want to do this with a C# .Net program?

Comment: Apparently you do, judging from the close votes building up...

Comment: @BoltClock: Yeah, unfortunately... thanks for the heads up anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

arccording to this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314960 deleteing the font file should be enough

Comment: This doesn't mention anything about doing so programmatically... but the information may still apply the same, its hard to tell

Comment: It's impossible to say whether the shell isn't doing some other work behind the scenes.

Comment: Nah. I think fonts are enumerated by scanning the fonts folder on request. Deleting the font file should do the trick. Correlating a filename to a font name might be tricky though.

Comment: @spender: I actually have the file names already so that part is not a problem... I think I will just give this a go and then see if I can find any references to the font anywhere

Comment: How can we delete font files? I get `UnauthorizedAccessException` & some security exceptions.

Comment: deleteing the font file not working for me, I checked it out on Windows 10.

Comment: I don't believe it's possible in more recent versions of Windows as the OS now "locks" font files, even in application directories.  They cannot be deleted by hand through the desktop, either, without a lot of fuss.  This makes it difficult to install newer versions of fonts or properly remove (on first pass) fonts during an uninstall.